# How do I avoid this race condition with readdir/inotify?

Tags: linux, inotify, readdir

Suppose I want to invoke some command on all files in a directory and set a watch to invoke that command on all files that get created in that directory.  If I do:

```c
while( ( sdi = readdir( d )) != NULL ) { ... }
closedir( d );
/* Files created here will be missed */
inotify_add_watch( ... );
```

then some files will potentially be missed.  If I call `inotify_add_watch()` before the `readdir()`, files may be acted on twice (it would require a fair bit of infrastructure to prevent acting twice, and it seems that the edge cases would be difficult to handle).  Is there a simple way to avoid having to record the names of all files worked on during the `readdir` loop and comparing those to the names returned in the `inotify_event` structure?  I can
minimize the amount of necessary comparisons with:

```c
while( ( sdi = readdir( d )) != NULL ) { ... }
inotify_add_watch( ... );
while( ( sdi = readdir( d )) != NULL ) { /* record name */ ... }
closedir( d );
```

And usually the second `readdir()` loop will do nothing, but this feels like a bad hack.

Comment: I do not actually remember asking this question, and with a few more years experience, I will now answer it by saying that you shouldn't even try to avoid the race condition.  Make sure that whatever you are doing in the loop is idempotent, so that you don't care if you perform those actions multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can't. The more you hack, the more race conditions you'll get.

The simplest *actually working* solution is to set the watch before using `opendir()`, and keep a list (set) of already used names (or their hashes).

But this isn't perfect either. User can have the file open in a text editor; you fix it, user saves it and the directory contains unfixed file anyway, though it's on your list.

The best method would be to be able for the program to actually distinguish used files by their content. In other words, you set watch, call command on `readdir()` results, then call it on inotify results and let the command itself know whether the file is fine already or not.